# Boost Compilation Failed for Installation of LightGBM on Windows: Name clash for '<pC:\boost\boost-build\lib>libboost_atomic.a'

Tags: boost, lightgbm

I am trying to install LightGBM GPU version on Windows systems (I am using Anaconda on Windows for Python). I followed the  [installation guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/GPU-Windows.rst) from the beginning.

I have succefully completed the first two tasks:
Install the appropriate OpenCL SDK
Install MinGW

However, I encountered error after this command for Boost Compilation:

```
b2 install --build_dir="C:\boost\boost-build" --prefix="C:\boost\boost-build" toolset=gcc --with=filesystem,system threading=multi --layout=system release
```

The Error Message are as followed:

```
error: Name clash for 'libboost_atomic.a'
error:
error: Tried to build the target twice, with property sets having
error: these incompatible properties:
error:
error:     -  64
error:     -  32
error:
error: Please make sure to have consistent requirements for these
error: properties everywhere in your project, especially for install
error: targets.
```

Please share me any suggestions on how should I rectify the problem?